# Playframework, Converting JSON to Model (with Gson), saving model fails

Tags: java, json, playframework, gson, morphia

I'am trying to convert a JSON string into my model class. I'am using morphia within the play framework.

Here are the relevant lines of code:

```
public static void add(JsonObject body) {
    System.out.println(body); // -> {"title":"test2","url":"http://www.gmx.de","description":"eine beschreibung für das lesezeichen","tags":["tag1","tag2","tag3","tag5","tag0209135913598"],"is_private":true}
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Bookmark bookmark = gson.fromJson(body, Bookmark.class);
    System.out.println(bookmark.getClass().getName()); // -> models.Bookmark    
    bookmark.save();
```

But I think that I'am doing something wrong, because this code throws the following exception:

```
Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Bookmarks.java around line 40)
IllegalArgumentException occured : can't serialize class java.lang.Object

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: can't serialize class java.lang.Object
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't serialize class java.lang.Object
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder._putObjectField(BSONEncoder.java:234)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putIterable(BSONEncoder.java:259)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder._putObjectField(BSONEncoder.java:198)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:140)
    at org.bson.BSONEncoder.putObject(BSONEncoder.java:86)
    at com.mongodb.OutMessage.putObject(OutMessage.java:190)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:253)
    at com.mongodb.DBApiLayer$MyCollection.insert(DBApiLayer.java:217)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.insert(DBCollection.java:71)
    at com.mongodb.DBCollection.save(DBCollection.java:633)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:764)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:826)
    at com.google.code.morphia.DatastoreImpl.save(DatastoreImpl.java:820)
    at play.modules.morphia.Model.save2(Model.java:705)
    at play.modules.morphia.Model.save(Model.java:692)
    at controllers.Bookmarks.add(Bookmarks.java:40)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    ... 1 more
```

It seems like that the following line is throwing this exception:

```
bookmark.save();
```

Here is the code of the model:

```
@AutoTimestamp
@Entity
public class Bookmark extends Model {
    public String title;
    public String url;
    public String description;
    @Indexed
    public List tags;
    public boolean is_private;

    public Bookmark() {}

    public Bookmark(String title,
                    String url,
                    String description,
                    List tags,
                    boolean is_private)
    {
        this.title          = title;
        this.url            = url;
        this.description    = description;
        this.tags           = tags;
        this.is_private     = is_private;
    }
}
```

My question now is how I can fix this, or how I have to create a model instance based on the json input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is throwing an error because [fromJson()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html) only accepts `String` or `Reader` objects, you're passing in a `JsonObject`.

But because Play! uses [POJO binding](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/controllers#pojo) it's probably better to do something like:

```
public static void add(Bookmark newBookmark) {  
    // Validation etc ..
    bookmark.save(); 
}
```

If you really want to work with Gson then something like this might work (based on looking at [the docs](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.2.3/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html)):

```
public static void add(JsonObject body) {  
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(body, Bookmark.class);
    Bookmark bookmark = gson.fromJson(json, Bookmark.class);
    bookmark.save(); 
}
```

Comment: Okay, I tried the second solution but it doesn't really work. Calls to add() always resulted in "can't serialize class java.lang.Object". So I'am now using something like a "middle way" .. a "translation" object with the same attributes like my model - I use this object to fill it with the json data and then I create a model based on that object ... that works for me ... maybe not the best/elegant way - but for the moment it works.

Comment: Anyway, your tip about JsonObject->toJson was useful.